# unity desktop workspace switcher 16.04 two monitor goes black

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my home pc, and work pc.
I have two monitor both.
New problem seen in last month in 16.04 and this problem is after try change one windows position one monitor goes black.

sane picture:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This conflict is `desktop work-space expo` with `Wobbly Windows plugin` when you have two monitors or more and enable both.

You can disable `Wobbly Windows plugin` for fix this problems.

Or if you don't want disable `Wobbly Windows plugin` there's another way:

Go to **compizconfig settings manager > expo plugin > Appearance > multi Output mode item >** change **one big wall** to **good view**.

This problem emerged in 16.04 and has not so far been fixed in newer versions.